# Слетает верстка ThimPress (Wordpress) шаблона в браузере Safari

Tags: css, wordpress

Прошу о помощи знатоков wp, сам я не смог найти в какую сторону копать.

**Проблема:** (только) в браузере сафари при прокрутке (скролле) страниц некоторых статей слетает верстка (переформируется DOM).

**Снимок экрана проблемы:** https://yadi.sk/i/a371nKioyH1Uyw

**Как повторить:**

1. открыть статью и прокрутить до конца вниз;
2. прокручивать обратно, вверх;
3. поверх контента появляется футер и / или сайдбар.

**Примеры таких страниц:**

http://142.93.111.137/education/?p=353

http://int20.ru/?p=467

- Сайт работает на wordpress.
- Ссылка на пример (ThimPress education pack):  https://thimpress.com/product/education-pack-1-free-education-wordpress-theme/
- Можно проверить на доменах:

http://int20.ru

http://142.93.111.137

Answer (score 1):

Решением проблемы было удаление bootstrap.